# How to detect DTMF tones in Twilio's android sdk

Tags: android, sdk, twilio, dtmf

I am using Twilio Voice SDK on android to initiate a call to a normal phone number.

I need to be able to detect from within the app that initiated the call that the person on the phone pressed one of the keypad keys.

**I cannot find a counterpart in the Voice SDK to call.sendDigits() for detecting DTMF tones.**

I have tried a couple of approaches and am thinking of a third:

1. The most obvious approach was to find an api call for registering a listener to DTMF or a listener to Digits but I cannot find one.

   **NOTE:** in my tests I noticed that when I send DTMF tones from the phone to the android device, I can hear abbreviated tones in the android device so Twilio seems to be processing the tones and letting through a modified version of them.
2. The second approach was to find a library that could detect the tones from the audio stream and I found several posts that point to the Goertzel algorithm.  I found a library (TarsosDSP) that implements the algorithm and seems easy to use.  However, I cannot figure out how to get a hold of the audio stream from the twilio call.
3. The third approach (I have not tried yet because it seems too hacky... but I might get desperate enough) is to use twiml to detect the tones on the twilio server (using the Gather verb)... I will need to figure out how to have twilio listen in on an active conversation and then figure out how to have the twiml send a signal to my android device once it detects the DTMF.

It seems likely that Twilio does have a mechanism to register a listener to DTMF tones in the SDK and that I'm just not looking in the right places... that would be the best solution.

Comment: Can I ask why you want to detect DTMF tones when you have a conversation set up between two people? There's nothing built into the SDK for this, but I'd love to dig in further to see what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi @philnash. This application is a doorphone so I need the tenant who received the phone call to be able to press a key on their phone to open the door.  What do you think of approach 3?

Comment: You could use [`hangUpOnStar`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#hanguponstar) for the tenant to get out of the call, then have the call progress to use `<Gather>` to take the input and open the door?

Comment: @philnash This is a good suggestion.  I'll look into it.  Do you know if my code will know the difference between a disconnect via * versus just hanging up?  Thank you!

Comment: You wouldn't know the difference between the two types of hangups, which is why I'd suggest continuing to `<Gather>` another response. `hangUpOnStar` allows the user to get out of a `<Dial>` call without physically hanging the phone up and means you can go on to other actions and that's the difference.